# copy directory into same directory with tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a copy of a Web site checked out with Tortoise SVN.  We are making a Spanish version of the site, and I need to copy the en/ directory, paste it in the same directory, rename it es/ and then commit it back to the repo.  How do I do that?

Comment: You need to create a new branch.

Comment: The en/ dir is just one of the dirs within the site.  It's just some text files.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Drag the folder from the right list view in explorer to the same folder in the tree view on the left. When you release the mouse button, the drag context menu is shown where you will see multiple entries added by TortoiseSVN. One of them is `SVN copy and rename`. Or you could just use `SVN copy` - TortoiseSVN will detect that the file/folder already exists and ask for a new name.